Images and menu links disapearing after saving
I am using Wp Bakery on a salient theme and have a bug where images or background images on 2 specific pages don't save or show once added.
This also appears on the menu widgets, I will add a custom link then the URL field on the custom link will not appear when editing or when saved.



Are you running the latest WPBackery version ?

Yes, it came with the theme
Salient Wp Bakery 7.6
Salient theme 16.2.2

Unfortunately WP Bakery and Theme specific questions are off topic.  There isn't even a guarantee that if you're using the newest version of a theme like Salient that you have the newest WP Bakery version. I've actually seen themes have customized/changed version of WP Bakery.  You'll need to hop onto ThemeForest and see if the Salient devs can help.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Those were to add detail to the question and avoid the questions on theme and builder.
The photos I posted are about the menu items. not the theme/builder, I have worked around those
